# C++ Student Class

Tags: c++, classes

Is this a good approach of designing a class or is there some other way that I am not aware of?

**Student.h**
specification file

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    private:
        int ID;
        string name;
        double GPA; 
        char gender;
    public:
        Student();
        Student(int ID, string name, double GPA, char gender);
        void setStudent(int ID, string name, double GPA, char gender);
        int getID();
        string getName();
        double getGPA();
        char getGender();
        void print();
};
#endif
```

**Student.cpp** 
implementation file

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Student :: Student()
{
    ID = 0;
    name = "";
    GPA = 0;
    gender = ' ';
}
Student :: Student(int ID, string name, double GPA, char gender)
{
    this -> ID = ID;
    this -> name = name;
    this -> GPA = GPA;
    this -> gender = gender;
}

void Student :: setStudent(int ID, string name, double GPA, char gender)
{
    this -> ID = ID;
    this -> name = name;
    this -> GPA = GPA;
    this -> gender = gender;
}

int Student ::  getID()
{
    return ID;
}

string Student :: getName()
{
    return name;
}

double Student :: getGPA()
{
    return GPA;
}

char Student ::  getGender()
{
    return gender;
}

void Student :: print()
{
    cout << "ID : " << ID << endl;
    cout << "Name : " << name << endl;
    cout << "GPA : " << GPA << endl;
    cout << "Gender : " << gender << endl;
}
```

**StudentDemo.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Student s;
    int ID;
    string name;
    double GPA; 
    char gender;

    cout << "Enter ID ";
    cin >> ID;
    cout << "Enter name ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter GPA ";
    cin >> GPA;
    cout << "Enter gender ";
    cin >> gender;
    s.setStudent(ID, name, GPA, gender);
    s.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should add '_' before your private members to help recognizing which member can be accessed publicly and which can not.

Comment: @AntiMoron: Names prefixed with underscores are actually reserved in a number of cases in C++. And if you're encapsulating right, you won't have public member variables anyway.

Comment: @cHao I though class members have their scope protection against redeclaration problem. Where underscores are reserved is just in macros. Could you give me some links about the cases you mentioned?

Comment: @AntiMoron: C++11 §17.6.4.3.2: "- Each name that contains a double underscore `__` or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (§2.2) is reserved to the implementation for any use.  - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace."  A name like `_ID` is reserved. Could be anything...a custom keyword, even. Better to avoid the mess. There's no point in highlighting private variables anyway; hell, since we're dirtying up names, let's rather pollute the _public_ ones, cause you should feel dirty using one. :)

Comment: @AntiMoron No, **do not** decorate different members.  The `public` or `private` section enforces the usage.

Answer (score 12):

## Student.cpp

**Initializer lists**

You should use initializer lists in place of these constructors.  They offer some advantages, such as being able to initialize `const` members.  Normal constructors do not allow that.

The initializer list is in this form:

> ```
> Class::Class() : member(value) /* additional members separated by commas */ {}
> ```

Here's what it'll look like with the overloaded constructor:

```
Student::Student(int ID, std::string const& name, double GPA, char gender)
    : ID(ID)
    , name(name)
    , GPA(GPA)
    , gender(gender)
{}
```

You should then apply the same idea to the other constructor.

**Overloading `operator<<`**

Consider overloading `operator<<` for `Student` so that it'll be easier to output.

Declare it in the header:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Student const& obj);
```

Define it in the implementation:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Student const& obj)
{
    out << "ID: " << obj.ID << "\n";
    out << "Name: " << obj.name << "\n";
    out << "GPA: " << obj.GPA << "\n";
    out << "Gender: " << obj.gender << "\n";

    return out;
}
```

**Overloading `operator>>`**

You can also do the same with `operator>>` to make inputting cleaner.

Declare it in the header:

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Student& obj);
```

Define it in the implementation:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Student& obj)
{
    return in >> obj.ID >> obj.name >> obj.GPA >> obj.gender;
}
```

Regarding `name`: you should use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `std::cin >>` so that spaces can be properly handled (it's also preferred in general for inputting into an `std::string`).  However, it'll require a call to [`std::ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) as you cannot just mix both forms of input.

## StudentDemp.cpp

You should construct the `Student` object instead of using a setter.

If you keep your user inputs as-is, this is how the construction should look:

```
Student s(ID, name, GPA, gender);
```

But if you decide to use `operator>>`, you just need the default `Student`:

```
Student s;
```

and your input will now look like this:

```
std::cout << "Enter student information (ID, name, GPA, gender):";
std::cin >> s;
```

With the latter, you should then remove the other variables from the top of the function.

## Final notes:

- Please do not use `using namespace std` in so many places.  It can cause name-clashing issues, especially in larger programs.  While it is okay to use it in a lower scope (such as a function), it's *especially* worse to use it in a header file.  Any file including the header will be forced to use it, which could cause bugs.  Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more information.
- Declare variables as close in scope as possible to help ease maintainability.  This is apparent with your variables declared at the top of `main()`.
- Avoid setters and getters as much as possible.  They can break encapsulation as they expose the internals of the class.  In this particular program, you won't even need them if you're just displaying values.  Remove them all and it should make the code cleaner.

Comment: `using namespace std` in a header (or before including a header) is obviously problematic, but even Herb Sutter uses it in non-header files all the time so I strongly disagree with the first note. Apart from that using a char for gender is a bad design I'd say.

Comment: @Voo: Then you need to read [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065). Please provide an example of your speculation about Herb so we can comment on the situation (as all usage is dependent on the situation (in the general case it is a bad idea and the advice here holds)).

Comment: @Voo: I do agree about the gender thing, and I haven't quite looked at that.  I suppose an `enum` would be a better option?

Comment: @Loki "You can and should use namespace using declarations and directives liberally in your implementation files after #include directives and feel good about it. Despite repeated assertions to the contrary, namespace using declarations and directives are not evil and they do not defeat the purpose of namespaces. Rather, they are what make namespaces usable." Item 59, in C++ Coding Standards. Also most of his example code you can find. I also distinctly remember STL using it in his coding during Going Native, etc.

Comment: I find an IDE with real time syntax checking makes the name clash argument largely passe.  I've studied several examples and have yet to see a significant compiled size difference between code using namespace std, and code not using it.

Comment: Getters and setters are usefull, because of encapsulation, and thus you have a more stable API. In case you would want to store `gender` as a `Enum` instead of a char you would run into trouble. Also, wouldn't it be better to make `operator<<` non-friend, and use the getters?

Comment: Without setters for the private member, they could be `const`, I guess.

Comment: Re Herb: Don’t forget “slide code” does not follow the same standards.  @Voo, using *declarations* in your CPP file is fine; *directives* are problematic.  There are some namespaces *meant* to be used in a *using directive*; `std` in particular should never be.

Comment: @I'lladdcommentstomorrow If you do that, the default assignment operator will not be generated.

Answer (score 10):

It's a fine starting point.

### Overall Design

But if I was to classify it at the moment it really a property bag (a set of properties with no associated actions (thus not a class)). A class is a set of properties that have meaning together. The state of an object of that class is manipulated by actions that are associated with the class.

#### Getter/Setters

This is why I also hate Getters/Setters.

```
   int getID();
    string getName();
    double getGPA();
    char getGender();
```

They provide no intrinsic value and expose implementation details about your class. Sure there are sometimes reasons to have them but usually it is better to provide appropriate methods that manipulate the state of the class rather the just giving access to the members.

#### Extended Setter

I see no reason for a set method:

```
void Student :: setStudent(int ID, string name, double GPA, char gender)
```

What is the use case?

```
Student   loki(5, "Loki", 4.8 /* So much better than you would expect*/, 'A');


// Change the value of the variable?
loki.setStudent(8, "Deepak", 1.0, 'M');
```

Sounds like a resonable use case. But it has so many detractors (You have to manually set all the values). Why not just set if from another student object.

```
Student   loki(5, "Loki", 4.8 /* So much better than you would expect*/, 'A');

loki = Student(8, "Deepak", 1.0, 'M');  // Reset loki to a different student.
```

#### Default construction: Hmmmm

```
Student :: Student()
{
    ID = 0;
    name = "";
    GPA = 0;
    gender = ' ';
}
```

After construction an object is supposed to be in a valid state. But this does not look very valid to me. When you write other code you make assumptions about the objects you use. One of these assumptions is that the objects are in a valid state so you can just use them (you don't need to validate them because the object validated itself on construction and any members validate that mutations are correct).

What if I write a print function:

```
 void printGenScore(Student const& s1)
 {
      std::cout << "I am " << s1.getGender() << " - " << s1.getGPA() << "\n";
 }
```

If I use this with the default student:

```
 Student s1;
 printGenScoew(s1);

 // I get the output
 // I am  - 
 //
```

Does not look like a big problem. As a human I can read that as a blank user. But now you are assuming the text will be read by a human and not some other piece of code that expects the input to be in a very precise format as another group has written the code:

```
 void scoreByGenederBigDataParser(std::istream& f)
 {
     std::string  res;
     std::char    gender;
     float        score;

     f >> res >> res >> gender >> res >> score;
     data[gender] += score;
 }
```

Now all hell breaks loose as their assumptions have been broken.

### Review of C++

Lets stop doing this.

```
using namespace std;
```

Its lazy and leads to bad habbits. There issues associated with bringing stuff into the current namespace. So don't do it. Look up why.

```
std::cout << "Hi\n"; // Its not that hard to add `std::` to stuff.
```

#### Prefer Initializer lists

Use the initializer list from the constructor. And don't bother with `this->` its not very common in C++ circles.

Some people say if you use `this->` it prevents errors. True; but then you are only relying on your eyes rather than the compiler to find errors.

If you turn the warning level of your compiler up and treat warnings as errors. Then you get even better error protection and you don't need the ugly `this->` as it does not help you find errors anymore (as the compiler is doing it for you).

```
Student :: Student(int ID, string name, double GPA, char gender)
   : ID(ID)
   , name(name)
   , GPA(GPA)
   , gender(gender)
{}
```

Note Getters don't change the state. So make them const.

#### Student::print

Don't limit your printing to `std::cout`. Pass a stream that defaults to std::cout but allows the user to pass the stream type they want.

Don't use std::endl (prefer "\n") unless you want to flush the buffer. You usually don't want to flush the buffer. Flushing is an efficiency thing and the standard flush cycle is designed to make the stream very efficient. If you force a flush you will probably make the code slower (unless you know what you are doing). For I/O operations with the user `std::cin` and `std::cout` are synced. So if you ask a question the output is automatically flushed so they can read it before providing an answer.

print does not alter the state of the object. So it should be marked as `const`

```
class Student
{
    void print(std::ostream& str = std::cout) const
    {
        str << "ID : " << ID << "\n"
            << "Name : " << name << "\n"
            << "GPA : " << GPA << "\n"
            << "Gender : " << gender << "\n"
    }
};
```

Now you can also add the standard stream operator that most people in C++ use.

```
std::osteam& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Student const& data)
{
     data.print(str);
     return str;
}

Student   loki(5, "Loki", 4.8, 'A');
std::cout << loki;
```

Answer (score 5):

> Student.h specification file

Did you mean header?

- You should not use `using namespace std` in header files: use `std::` instead.
- You don't need two constructors: you can use default parameters.
- In function prototypes you could omit the names, because the compiler will ignore them.

Other things I'd change, IMHO:

- Take advantage of `class` default access specification: remove the `private` specifier since they're already private.
- If you allow the user to set data through `setters` but you don't check what he's actually putting, there's no difference if they were directly `public`.

> Student.cpp

- In `print`, you'd better to flush the buffer only once
- Pass `string` as `const &`, if you aren't going to modify it.
- Consider using the `operator<<` in order to make the output process sweeter. (you could just call `print` inside)

> Blockquote StudentDemo.cpp

- Where `main` resides, the file should be named `main.cpp`

If you follow all my advices, you'll get:

Student.h

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#include <string>
using std::string;

struct Student
{
        Student(int ID = 0, const string &name = " ", double GPA = 0.0f, char gender = ' ');
        void setStudent(int ID, string name, double GPA, char gender);
        void print();

    int ID;
    string name;
    double GPA; 
    char gender;

};
#endif
```

Student.cpp

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Student :: Student(int ID , const string &name , double GPA, char gender )
{
    this -> ID = ID;
    this -> name = name;
    this -> GPA = GPA;
    this -> gender = gender;
}

void Student :: print()
{
    cout << "ID : " << ID << '\n'
     << "Name : " << name << '\n'
     << "GPA : " << GPA << '\n'
     << "Gender : " << gender << endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Student s;

    cout << "Enter ID ";
    cin >> s.ID;

    cout << "Enter name ";
    cin >> s.name;

    cout << "Enter GPA ";
    cin >> s.GPA;

    cout << "Enter gender ";
    cin >> s.gender;

    s.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"In function prototypes you could omit the names, because the compiler will ignore them."* If you have an IDE, the parameter names can be displayed when calling a function. It's not a replacement for a proper documentation, but helps at least to get the order right.

Comment: don’t use `this->` to refer to members.  In the constructor you want to use the init list, which allows parameters to have the same name.  Why use a float constant as a default for a double parameter?  Is (space) for a name really a useful default, esp. given that it cannot be changed?  I would think that it has no defaults.

Answer (score 1):

At least you should have such member function declarations.

```
int getID() const;
string getName() const;
double getGPA() const;
char getGender() const;
void print() const;
```

By adding const specifers can make const objects access the member function.

In addition, if you focus on exception safety. You should add `noexcept` specifer on depends which indicates the function won't throw any exception.